# C++ call method from Object of other class

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I've got a little Problem with my actual university Project and were at the beginning of C++ before we did C. The Problem is that I want to call a method of an object which i've got with a pointer. The class is called Mainwindow and it has a object pointer of the class Camera `Camera* cam;` the class Camera has the function to turn right, left, up and so on. Now I have a Callback in the Mainwindow for the mouse and it should call the camera to turn. I've tried to do this `cam->turnRight();` or `cam.turnRight();` both of this won't work. The Method in Mainwindow where the Camera is called to turn is static, because Callbacks have to be static.

Mainwindow is not a Singleton.

Do you have any Idea how to make the call complete?

Thanks in advance,

Criska48

Comment: Are these turnMethods made public using 'public' keyword?

Comment: Didn't work is not descriptive. How did it not work? And post the code for a short compilable verifiable example.

Comment: A description of code is not as helpful in diagnosing problems with said code as the posting of code.  Most problems that entail a lot of code can be reduced to simpler examples of under 30 lines of code that still represent the concepts at work.  Once you've gone through the exercise of creating a self-contained, compilable code example that demonstrates your query, we'll be able to be far more helpful.

Comment: These functions are public. I will add code below.

Comment: Give us a chance by pasting compiler output to body of your question, otherwise our only answer would be 'We have no idea'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, static member functions cannot access any member variables because there is no object associated with that static member function. There are several ways that you can pass in an instance of Camera:

1) Pass in a pointer to the Camera object you want to turn to the static function (this is probably the best solution)

2) Make the Camera object pointer in Mainwindow static also and call it with Mainwindow::camera. This does mean that you can only have one camera object for all of your Mainwindow objects though and you are essentially creating a global variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I understand your meaning and your solution will work because actually we will only have one mainwindow. Maybe i have to add a Singleton later. Mainwindow::cam->turnRight(); does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You try to access a non-static data member `cam` from a static member function. This will not work, and cannot work, because in the static member function compiler cannot know from which object's `cam` it should use.

Since you need to use static functions because of the callbacks issue, you need to redesign your code. How? hard to say without the actual code in your question.

Comment: You're also right and maybe there will be a solution if I would give you the code, but the answer below had a fast solution.